# How to update a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter's query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

If I have a `Query a`, and I'm setting it to a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Then, I want to **constantly** create a new `Query` and update the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

E.G:

```
query = database.orderByChild("child");
query2 = database.orderByChild("child2"); 
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<...>(...,...,...,query){
   ...
}
```

Now, after 3 seconds, I'm looking for a method to change the query. Similar to this:

```
adapter.setQuery(query2);
```

Is there an existing method for this? Or was Firebase, like always, too lazy to even work on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database queries are immutable: you cannot change the properties of an existing query.

Since the adapters in FirebaseUI are mostly a reflection of the underlying data structure, we have not added the option to change the query for an existing adapter either.

When I create a new query, I also create a new adapter and tie *that* to the (list or recycler) view.

What advantage do you see of replacing the query under the existing adapter over creating a new adapter for the new query?

Comment: The advantage is I don't have to wait for Firebase to implement its filtering without wasting bandwidth.

Comment: puf the clear advantage is runtime filtering. Take SearchView for example, if I can tie the search phrase to a new/updated query I can achieve filtering. Please update the post in case you have added client side filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Adapter class to accomplish this but its not fully optimal. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53235783/683658