# update firebase list adapter when a user filter data by choosing a drop down menu

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

how to update my firebase list adapter when a user filter data by choosing a drop down menu .The menu contains string value, my code is as follows :

```
FirebaseListAdapter<blood> adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<blood>(this, blood.class, R.layout.blod,mref) {

        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, blood model, int position)
        {
            final String pskey=getRef(position).getKey();
            TextView name_,groiup;
            ImageView Pic;
            groiup=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bldgrp);
            name_=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name1);
            Pic=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.pic);
            name_.setText(model.getName());
            groiup.setText(model.getBlodgrp());
}
```

Comment: You cannot change the query of a FirebaseListAdapter after it's been created. You'll have to create a new adapter and tie that to the view. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919636/how-to-update-a-firebaserecycleradapters-query/40923600#40923600

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how to tie to new adapter as i am using firebase list adapter.The firebase team should incorporate the offline filter or search mechanism to firebase list adapter.or else there is no way to use it..

Answer (score 0):

Once a `FirebaseListAdapter` is created, it cannot be changed because all queries in Firebase are [immutable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query).

Because the adapters that exists in FirebaseUI represents in fact the data structure it self, Firebase creators did not add a option that allow you to change the query for a given adapter.

Note, that when a new query is created, a new adapter is also created. So, as a conclusion, to solve the problem in your case you just need to create a new adapter.

Hope it helps.