# The imagebutton isn't commiting to the change in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

thanks for helping. I was trying to implement an add to favorite function in my recycler view, everything is  working fine except for one thing. I am unable to commit the changed  image button in my recycler view, every time I press the button, the post is added to the  favorites and the image button turns yellow, but as soon as I move to some other fragment, the yellow button goes back to its initial stage. Can anyone of you help me on how can I make my button commit to the changes in recycler view. Below is my relevant code.

Initialization of buttons in holder class:

```
class UsersViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        private ImageButton mFavouritesBlack, mFavouritesYellow;
        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        private Heart mHeart;


        public UsersViewHolder1(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
            mFavouritesBlack = mView.findViewById(R.id.ad_start_fav);
            mFavouritesYellow = mView.findViewById(R.id.ad_start_fav1);
       }
}
```

OnBindViewHOlder class(I omitted the irrelevant code):

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UsersViewHolder1 Holder, final int position, @NonNull
                    Ad ad) {
                Holder.setTitle(ad.getTitle());
                Holder.setPrice(ad.getPrice());
                Holder.setCategory(ad.getCategory());
                Holder.setImage(ad.getImage(), getContext());
                Holder.setTime(ad.getTime());


                String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();
                final String kk = user_id.toString();

                Holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent mew = new Intent(getActivity(), ExpandActivity.class);
                        mew.putExtra("user_id", kk);
                        startActivity(mew);

                    }
                });


                Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                        mFav.child(puid).child(kk).child("fav_status").setValue("Added as fav").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Added to Fav",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                if (Holder.mFavouritesBlack.isShown())
                                Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        mFav.child(puid).child(kk).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Removed from Fav",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                if (Holder.mFavouritesYellow.isShown())
                                Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: Can u explain why you have two image buttons and when each of them should be hidden/shown

Comment: I have two buttons one have a star border and the other one has star filled with yellow color, initially black star is visible but when user presses on it, the yellow star becomes visible and the post is added to the favorites and also the black one  goes invisile and sam eh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of messed up searches and work I finally removed my the problem was that recycler view isn't able to hold the state by itself after  change, that's why we need to provide a way to store the state (or the image in my case) so that it can remember it everytime it recycles the view, but instead I added the direct statement through which it checks whether the favourite node is present in database or not and based on that  the buttons behaved. Below is the code.

```
 mFav.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   if (dataSnapshot.child(puid).hasChild(kk)){
                       Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                   }else{
                       Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
 Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    mFav.child(puid).child(kk).child("fav_status").setValue("Added as fav").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Added to Fav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (!itemStateArray.get(adapterPosition, false))
                                Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
            });
            Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    mFav.child(puid).child(kk).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Removed from Fav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (itemStateArray.get(adapterPosition, false))
                                Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

But huge thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to implement is  selection inside a recyclerview which requires saving state, that is you will have to save the favourite items say in a SparseBooleanArray which can be used to save favourite adapter positions, and inside onBindViewHolder check if the favourites array contains the adapter position and toggle imageview (There is no need to use two images instead you can change the color of drawable), please refer [this artcle](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022)

Comment: I used the drawable before it worked the same but I prefer this one better, and thanks for your response but I have no idea how to implement it, can you please help a bit with the  code part just a hint would be enough

Comment: Can you affort to add a selected state in your Model class like isFavourite?

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are saving the flags when a click happened,but when the views are redrawn you are not resetting the images accordingly. Inside the onBindViewHolder add the following code.

```
//Replace the if condition statement with the state value check(Abstract code shown below)
if(mFav.child(puid).child(kk).child("fav_status").getValue(),equals("Added as fav")){
  Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
  Holder.mFavouritesBlack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  Holder.mFavouritesYellow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: can you be specific though? Inside the OnBindViewHolder method, can you access if the item is added to favorites or not?

Comment: Where are you saving the state of the favorite button click? Firebase?

Comment: Thanks brother but it didn't helped but thanks for your effort,upvote for your effort.

Comment: Sure, thanks. But im trying to understand why. Looks like it is straightforward.

Comment: I was suggesting something on the similar lines. Anyway, cool.

Comment: Also, you can accept your own answer. It'll help people facing similar problems. And do follow [Ramees'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6835152/ramees-thattarath) suggestions for the imageview changes.